# Close and other popups are too wide and too far right

Tags: bug, design, user-interface

Since today, this is how the close popup dialog looks like when it pops up on my screen.

[image: close dialog screenshot]

I have to scroll right or move the dialog to see the right-hand side of the popup, in particular the action button. Even if I move the popup, it doesn't completely fit. Having a very wide dialog appear with a wide margin on its left, and a large chunk of the dialog hidden on the right, is not helpful.

The same problem occurs other popups: flag (fits on my screen, but the wide left margin causes it to be partially hidden on the right), mod (likewise).

Yes, I know that your marketing research has shown that I don't exist. But please don't get out of your way to make my life more difficult. At least until yesterday I didn't have this particular annoyance, so you can do better.

How do I get the popups to appear inside my screen? My window is wide enough for all the normal useful content of the page, so I expect popups to fit too.

Comment: Also a problem for me on my 12" Chromebook, where I have to zoom the text a bit to make it readable. There are already a few parts that (needlessly) don't *quite* fit; bit disappointing to see those parts increase, rather than decrease!

Comment: Also a problem for me. SE is starting to stand out in my general browsing experience as one of the few sets of sites that don't have responsive designs and assume obscene amounts of screen real-estate by default. This particular new annoyance is just the latest in a long chain...

Answer (score 4):

Weird. Nothing changed on our end in terms of how we're centering popups. Or at least, nothing that I'm aware of or have been able to dig up in source history.

Either way - yeah, this behaviour is neither optimal nor intended. I have a potential fix ready, but I need to do more testing on it than I can reliably do on a Friday afternoon before a long weekend. Early next week, most likely.